# PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle

I have this error from this code

> ORA-00907:  missing right parenthesis

```
select buyer
,cobuyer
, case
            when Sp_Desc like('ma%') then 'mail'
            when Sp_Desc like('pa%') then 'phone'      
            else " "
            end AS Special_Handling 
            from
              ( string_function(g.buyer_id)
                from gift g ) AS Sp_Desc  
, salary
, etc
```

Comment: It's not clear where you think the columns like `buyer`, `cobuyer`, `salary` are supposed to come from. You can't use `AS` for a table alias. Also, `" "` is invalid - probably should be `' '`.

Comment: The buyer and co-buyer are just select statements and I added to note that the case is in the middle of several select statements. What I tried to acomplish is to 1: Generate Sp_Desc in this statement: string_function(g.buyer_id)  AS Sp_Desc and use it on a case statement to create the Special_Handling column in this statement: , case when Sp_Desc like('ma%') then 'mail' 
         when Sp_Desc like('pa%') then 'phone'
    else ' ' end 
  AS Special_Handling 
Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  buyer 
  , cobuyer 
  , case when Sp_Desc like('ma%') then 'mail' 
         when Sp_Desc like('pa%') then 'phone'
    else ' '
    end 
  AS Special_Handling 
from 
  ( SELECT string_function(g.buyer_id) from gift g ) Sp_Desc
```